# Error while installing snowflake-connector-python in windows python 3.12.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have been trying to install Snowflake connector python with the command

```
pip install snowflake-connector-python
```

on Windows OS and getting the following error. Python version 3.12.0

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\src\snowflake\connector\nanoarrow_cpp\ArrowIterator\nanoarrow_arrow_iterator.cp312-win_amd64.exp'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1104
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for snowflake-connector-python
Failed to build snowflake-connector-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for snowflake-connector-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: No, not yet i am not able to understand what exactly to do even after going through the Microsoft page

Comment: Yeah, it worked after reinstalling the Microsoft Visual Studio 2022. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Since the problem is with Microsoft Visual Studio 2022, if you can uninstall and reinstall it or use any other editor you will be good.

Your issue is not with `snowflake-connector-python` please follow this link to troubleshoot your **LNK1104** error.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1104?view=msvc-170&redirectedfrom=MSDN#feedback

Once your error is fixed try:

Creating a fresh virtual environment then:

```
pip install snowflake-connector-python
```

Also, make sure that you **Do Not** have `snowflake` package installed in your virtual machine.

If you have both the packages together `snowflake` and `snowflake-connector-python` then too you will get error.

Comment: Hi @Goku - stands with Palestine, I have restarted my system, uninstalled the snowflake and tried to install the snowflake connector. I'm still getting the same error. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Still having the install issues like above. Definitely not going to mess with my Visual Studio install and do manual environment changes in the hopes the snowflake connector install then works. Too bad!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't Visual Studio. The error indicates failure to build the wheel file for Snowflake Connector Python. This is because there is no available Snowflake Connector Python wheel for Python 3.12 yet.

You need to revert to Python 3.11 or earlier. Python 3.12 will be supported by Snowflake Connector Python version 3.70 which has not yet been released. See [Release Notes](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/blob/67df7b11451849a77ab7110a27239efe5012f48c/DESCRIPTION.md) for more information.